# CSS - use a horizontal scrollbar only

Tags: css

i need to use an horizontal scollbar only if the content of the div is longer than the width value.

so i write :

```
.viewgallerylist{width:920px; float:left; padding-top:20px; height:120px; border-bottom:1px #000000 solid; overflow-x: scroll;}
```

the problem is that the scrollbar are 2, 1 horizontal and 1 vertical. How to remove the vertical one? cheers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
.viewgallerylist {
    min-width: 920px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -ms-overflow-x: auto; /* IE8 */
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

(min-width doesn't work in IE6, in case you still want to support that dinosaur)

Answer (score 4):

overflow-x:scroll creates a horizontal scrollbar if the content exceeds the width of the container.
overflow-y:scroll creates a vertical scrollbar if the contents exceeds the height of the container.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
.viewgallerylist {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `overflow-y: hidden`.