# I need help trying to make a div only have the horizontal scroll bar

Tags: html, horizontal-scrolling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS - use a horizontal scrollbar only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742416/css-use-a-horizontal-scrollbar-only)

I am still relatively new to using HTML but I am trying to make a layout, and I am wanting to have a div with the width of 370px by 199px as the height and I only want to have the horizontal scroll bar.

This is code I am working with.

```
<div class="camodule" style="position: absolute; left: 727px; top:202px; width: 370px; height:199px; overflow: auto;"> 
    Images that go here are (h)199px by (w)119px
</div>
```

What do I need to change to ***only*** have the horizontal scroll bar?

**[Edit]** I should meantion that I have different size boxes and only want two of the boxes to scroll horizontally. I want to have pictures that are (h)199px by (w)119px and have them flow all together, I have tried to fix it by putting multiple images (6) right next to each other. But when I view the content, it only shows 3 of the 6 images that I put in the div.

This is the entire code, with the content that I am trying to use to have it scroll all together, say with 6 images and such.

This is the code [exact code](http://jsfiddle.net/bethmariechaos/v3k4p/) I am currently working with, and as you see it isn't working. I wish for it to only have the scroll bar for two boxes, not all of the boxes I have that are different sizes. I have seen what I am trying to achieve so I know it has to work some how.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set an inner dive to be longer than your outer div, and then set the `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` properties independently (while removing your existing overflow rule).

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xEy9E/1/)**

```
<div class="camodule" style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top:10px; width: 370px; height:199px;-ms-overflow-x: auto; overflow-x: auto;overflow-y:hidden;-ms-overflow-y: hidden; "><div style="width:1000px">Your long content here.</div></div>​
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div class="camodule" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; position: absolute; left: 727px; top:202px; width: 370px; height:199px;"></div>
```

The property `overflow-x` controls horizontal scroll and `overflow-y` controls vertical.

It's also easier to work with `CSS` in a stylesheets or using the style tag:

```
.camodule {    
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    left: 727px;
    top:202px;
    width: 370px;
    height: 199px;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably switch your CSS it an external style sheet as well. [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/xEy9E/2/).

HTML

```
<div class="camodule">
    <div class="camoduleContent">
        Content That Scrolls
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.camodule{
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top:10px;
    width: 370px;
    height:199px;
    -ms-overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y:hidden
}
.camoduleContent{
    width:1000px;
}

​
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change overflow to `overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden;` Some browsers may still show the y scroll but it will be grayed out.